# Documents and Indexes/Memcache - how to use from GCE or GKE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been wanting to use the "Documents and Indexes" feature of the Google Cloud platform, but due to the terribly constraints on AppEngine (e.g. I use gRPC, Cloud Endpoints etc etc). So instead I'm using GKE with Golang and it's all working good. My datastore is "Datastore" and I want to index some documents as I'm creating too many indexes that could result in exploding indexes.

How do we use the appengine search API from GKE? I get this error from Google Cloud Platform "not an App Engine context".. so does this mean that AppEngine standard gets the good stuff while users like me are left without these managed services and wondering if we will ever get these services?

So Google, will GKE/GCE users get:

- Documents and Indexes (Search API)
- Memcache service

Or do we have to roll up our own solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point you'll have to roll your own solution as App Engine search isn't available as a standalone product outside of App Engine Standard.

For caching you could follow the same advice given to App Engine Flexible users: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-redislabs-memcache

- Essentially use either Redis Labs Memcache/Redis Cloud offerings.

Comment: Thanks - this is useful. I don't want to manage infrastructure so it's a solution. I know it's a dumb question, but will these be available at all to non-appengine users? Could be a big leg-up on AWS and help gain customers. Any equivalent solution for indexing/searching documents? unfortunately for me, Redislabs is not yet available in GCP Australia.

Comment: You could always drop a line to our support (support@redislabs.com) and enquire about plans for making our service available in parts of the cloud.

Comment: Thanks for this - I emailed them regarding availability on GCP Australia (Sydney).